# How to fix 'mouse hold draggable element'

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to make an element that drags (follows pageX,pageY coordinates) when the mouse is pressed and held and being released with mouse up, but my function moveElement does not stop executing moving code even when bool elementSelected is false.

I've tried different ways to stop executing CSS changes but failed

```
let elementSelected = false;

$(".dragElement").on("mousedown", function() {
    elementSelected = true;
    $(".logs").text("Selected box");
    moveElement();
});

$(document).on("mouseup", function() {
    elementSelected = false
    $(".logs").text("Deselect box");
    moveElement();
})

function moveElement() {
    if (!elementSelected) {
        return;
    } else {
        $(document).on("mousemove", function(event) {
            $(".dragElement").css("top", event.pageY);
            $(".dragElement").css("left", event.pageX);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: You  mean the else block of moveElement does not stop executing?

Comment: I don't understand how to stop executing  $(document).on("mousemove"). once mouseUp occurres.  
one solution I found was adding if (elementSelected) statement inside $(document).on("mousemove") that But I don't know if its the best solution

Comment: That would seem to make sense

Comment: Look at this https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_ondrag.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery UI provides the draggable feature, you may try [it](https://jqueryui.com/draggable/) out.